# can't find driver for connecting to sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, gradle, ktorm

I am trying to connect to a sqlite database in an android app.

I thought is was a good idea to import [ktorm](https://www.ktorm.org/)

But I can't seem to add it as described in their quickstart.
in `build.gradle.kts`

```
android {
...
}

dependencies {
...
   implementation("org.ktorm:ktorm-core:3.6.0")
}
```

Note that the quickstart mentions `compile` instead of `implementation`. But I am getting nothing but errors if I use `compile` and can't really figure out why.

Not entirely sure if that is the reason for why I am getting this error when it runs?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:data.sqlite
```

Or am I doing something else wrong when trying to connect?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/issues?q=is%3Aissue+sqlite and https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/issues/28

Comment: You don't need a driver for SQLite in Android, the support is built-in but it is is not using JDBC.

Comment: @Robert could you elaborate a bit on that? I recall seeing the same, that there should be built in support for it. But how would I connect to it using an orm such as ktorm, who generally uses connection strings with jdbc in their [guides](https://www.ktorm.org/en/connect-to-databases.html)